# How to merge two or more environments

Tags: php, codeception, browser-automation, acceptance-testing

I'm writing an acceptance test suite and I have to make the environment easily configurable, but for this to work I need to be able to merge two or more environments (**geoLocation, browser, os, URLs**).

If I run: `.\codecept run tests\acceptance\acceptanceTestCest --env firefox` the tests start running without issues with any environment I choose.

Now my problem is that if I try to merge the environments: `.\codecept run tests\acceptance\acceptanceTestCest --env firefox,US` I get the following message:

> In Configuration.php line 306:
> [Codeception\Exception\ConfigurationException]
> Suite tests\acceptance\acceptanceTestCest.php was not loaded

And if I try to merge more than two environments I get this message:

> Too many arguments, expected arguments "command" "suite" "test".

This is how my **acceptance.suite.yml** looks like:

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: http://localhost
        - REST:
            depends: PhpBrowser
            url: 'http://localhost/api/'
        - \Helper\Acceptance
    config:
        WebDriver:
            host: 'user:key@hub.browserstack.com'
            port: 3214
            browser: chrome
            capabilities:
                os: Windows
                os_version: 10
                browserstack.local: true # for local testing
env:
    AU:
        modules:
            config:
                WebDriver:
                    capabilities:
                        browserstack.geoLocation: AU
    US:
        modules:
            config:
                WebDriver:
                    capabilities:
                        browserstack.geoLocation: US
    CA:
        modules:
            config:
                WebDriver:
                    capabilities:
                        browserstack.geoLocation: CA
    firefox:
        modules:
            config:
                WebDriver:
                    browser: firefox    
    safari:
        modules:
            config:
                WebDriver:
                    browser: safari
```

I looked everywhere for this issue and I did not find anyone that even encountered it. The closest thing I found was that tests would be ran only with the second environment.

I'm new to `Codeception` and probably I am missing something.
I read the documentation on https://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#Environments and I don't seem to do anything wrong from there.

Codeception version is **2.4.5**
PHP version is **7.2.8**
Operating system: **Windows Server 2012**
Installation type: **Composer 1.7.2**

Things I tried:

**Put the environments in _envs folder.

Put the environments in codeception.yml**

Also I have the project on Jenkins as well and merging environments works perfectly there, but if I try to download the exact same project and run it locally it still doesn't work.